# Inconsistent types for record fields

Tags: haskell, record

After reading around a bit, it seems that the current record situation in Haskell is a bit sticky.

Take, for example, the `StateT` newtype. Both [the code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/src/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#StateT)

```
newtype StateT s m a = StateT { runStateT :: s -> m (a,s) }
```

and [the docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.1.2/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html)

> **Constructors**
>
> `StateT`
>
> `runStateT :: s -> m (a, s)`

say that the type of `runStateT` is `s -> m (a,s)`. However, GHCi show that the type *really* is

```
> :t runStateT
runStateT :: StateT s m a -> s -> m (a,s)
```

Is there any explanation for this discrepancy? Do the identifier in the record and the function refer to two different things, which GHC magically resolves behind the scenes? Although I see why it is nice to write `s -> m (a,s)` in the record, it just seems *wrong*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually correct, remember that the name of a record field means two different things in different contexts,

1. A function from the type of the value it's in to the individual field.
2. A magical record field which can be used in pattern matching and construction

`GHCi` is telling you what the function means, but the docs are talking about the record field itself, not the function it will generate.

Essentially behind the scenes this

```
data Foo = Foo {fooy :: Int}
```

will generate

```
fooy :: Foo -> Int
fooy Foo{fooy=fooy} = fooy
-- Equivalently: fooy Foo{fooy=bar} = bar
```

This function `fooy` is what you toss around in code, but the docs are talking about the record selector, which we see in the `Foo{fooy=...}` part of our code.

Comment: @AndrewC Yes, but that's what GHC generates IIRC, I've edited with a clearer version

Answer (score 4):

The type of the `runStateT` *field* is `s -> m (a, s)`. The type of the `runStateT` *field accessor function* is `StateT s m a -> s -> m (a, s)`.

Let's take a simpler example:

```
data Foo = Bar {foo :: Int}
```

- The type of the `foo` *field* (i.e., the type of values you can put into the `Bar` constructor) is just `Int`.
- The type of the `foo` *function* is `Foo -> Int`.

To illustrate further:

```
Bar {foo = 5}
```

5 is clearly an `Int`.

```
let x = foo (Bar 5) in ...
```

Here `foo` is applied to `Bar 5`, which has type `Foo`. So `foo` is taking a `Foo` and giving us 5 — which is an `Int`.

Answer (score 0):

The **field** `runStateT` for the record is of type `s -> m (a,s)` BUT the (field accessor) **function**, also called `runStateT` is of type `StateT s m a -> s -> m (a,s)` i.e it returns the field value (of type `s -> m (a,s)`) for the record instance (of type `StateT s m a`)